# Grover.to_pdf: ReadableStream is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, grover

I have a Rails app that is using the Grover Ruby gem, and it converts HTML to images perfectly well, but when I try to convert it to a PDF as shown below, I get an error saying the `ReadableStream` is not defined.

```rb
html = ExportController
        .new
        .render_to_string({
                            template: '/export/index',
                            layout: 'pdf'
                          })
pdf = Grover.new(html).to_pdf
send_data pdf, filename: 'export', type: 'application/pdf'
```

I suspected that this had something to do with the dependencies, but they were all the proper versions and appeared to have no conflicts. I checked the GitHub issues, and there was nothing matching this problem, so I think it's something on my end, but I can't pinpoint it.

Comment: Googling "ReadableStream is not defined" turned up a lot of of Node/JS errors, not Ruby ones. Grover uses Puppeteer under the hood, which uses JS to drive things. Maybe make sure your puppeteer install is up-to-date, and maybe nodejs too.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried (see bottom paragraph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem here, in production, on AWS EC2. It was resolved  by downgrading the package to version 21.11.0.

```
yarn remove puppeteer

yarn add puppeteer@21.11.0
```